# Java DatagramChannel hangs

Tags: java, udp, nio, channel, bytebuffer

I am starting some Java NIO programming, and am building two separate Java programs. One is to create some random data to send by UDP, and the other is to receive this data and perhaps perform some processing on it.

In each class, I have defined the SIZE of the data that is to be sent/received, and the number of bytes to send or receive at a time (per packet) at 8 bytes. When I have a SIZE of 1024 bytes, I can turn on the receiver (which by default waits on some packets to arrive), after which I turn on the sender which sends the packets, and the receiver correctly receives these packets and terminates when all packets are received. I then tried to set SIZE to 10 megabytes. I start the receiver, and then start the sender. The sender seems to be working fine and terminates after a few seconds. The receiver starts working and proceeds to read a number of packets (I have put some printlns around the code). However, somewhere in the process, the receiver seems to hang and stops receiving more packets. I do not know where the hanging occurs, except that it happens right after the buffer is cleared for a new read.

Perhaps I'm using the library wrongly. Any help is much appreciated.

The sender class is called UDPSender as shown below:

```
    public class UDPSender {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Generate some data to send
            int SIZE=1024*1024*10;
            int bufferBytes = 8;

            byte[] b = new byte[SIZE];
            new Random().nextBytes(b);
            String value = new String(b);
            //System.out.println(value);

            // Create Datagram channel for sending UDP packets
            DatagramChannel sendingChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
            // Bind the channel to a specific sending socket address and port
            InetSocketAddress sendSocket = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9999);
            sendingChannel.socket().bind(sendSocket);

            //Target socket address
            InetSocketAddress targetSocket = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            //loop to send bufferBytes bytes at a time
            int location = 0;
            int bytesSent = 0;
            long startTime=0; long endTime=0; long elapsedTime=0;  // for speed benchmarking
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE / bufferBytes; i++) {
                //System.out.println(i);
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferBytes);
                buf.clear();
                buf.put(Arrays.copyOfRange(b, location, location + bufferBytes));
                location = location + bufferBytes;
                buf.flip();
                bytesSent = bytesSent + sendingChannel.send(buf, targetSocket);
            }
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
            double elapsedTimeMs = elapsedTime / 1000000.0;
            System.out.println("Elapsed:" + elapsedTimeMs + " msec");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UDPSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The second class is called UDPReceiver as shown below:

```
    public class UDPReceiver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int SIZE=1024*1024*10;
            int bufferBytes = 8;
            int packet_max = SIZE/bufferBytes;

            // Create Datagram channel for receiving UDP packets
            DatagramChannel receivingChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
            // Bind the channel to a specific receiving socket address and port
            InetSocketAddress receiveSocket = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",8888);
            receivingChannel.socket().bind(receiveSocket);
            // Set up address of send
            InetSocketAddress sendSocket = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",9999);
            // Connect our receiving socket to their sending socket address
            receivingChannel.connect(sendSocket);

            long startTime=0; long endTime=0; long elapsedTime=0;  // for speed benchmarking
            byte[] b = new byte[SIZE]; //receiving storage
            int packets=0; int location=0; int bytesCount; //byte[] indexes
            boolean clockStart=false;


            //try indirect ByteBuffer
            System.out.println("Indirect ByteBuffer()");
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferBytes);
            packets=0; location=0; bytesCount = 0; clockStart=false;
            while ((bytesCount = receivingChannel.read(buf)) > 0) { // Read data from file into ByteBuffer
                System.out.println(".");
                if(clockStart==false){
                    startTime = System.nanoTime();
                    clockStart=true;
                }
                // flip the buffer which set the limit to current position, and position to 0.
                buf.flip(); System.out.println("..");
                System.arraycopy(buf.array(), 0, b, location, buf.capacity()); System.out.println("..."); // Write data from ByteBuffer to bytearray
                location=location+bufferBytes; System.out.println("....");
                buf.clear();  System.out.println(".....");    // For the next read
                packets = packets+1; System.out.println("......");
                if(packets==packet_max){
                    System.out.println(".......");
                    System.out.println(packets);
                    break;
                }
            }
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("ByteBuffer() Elapsed Time is " + (elapsedTime / 1000000.0) + " msec");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            //Logger.getLogger(UDPReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 8 bytes? Eight bytes of payload and 28 bytes of UDP header overhead doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hi @EJP - Thanks for reading. I don't have any particular reason for the 8 bytes. It is just an example with which I am trying to learn about UDP, NIO etc. The same issue occurs even with larger payloads e.g. 64 bytes.

Comment: Some additional detail after debugging: I slowed down the UDPSender rate by inserting a Thread.sleep(1); after every sent packet, and now the receiver is able to go all through the cycle. Seems to be a limitation on the burst of UDP packets that can be accepted at one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't 'hang', it *blocks,* and it does that because you are trying to read a specific number of packets without any regard to the fact that UDP is unreliable. When you lose packets, as you will, your sender and receiver don't know about it, so your sender doesn't resend, and your receiver keeps trying to read to the entire number of packets, which will never arrive.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! When I slowed the transfer down, all packets were being received, and as the transfer was sped up, some packets were getting lost or not received in time, and therefore the process, as you say, kept waiting for more (exact number) packets that were never going to arrive since they got lost.

Side question - do you think it is realistic to use Java Sockets for high data rates e.g. 10Gb/s incoming packets? Alternatively perhaps it is a good idea to use some form of raw packet sniffing directly at the Ethernet interface. Is this possible with Java?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Java whatsoever. The question is whether it is appropriate to use UDP in this way, and the answer is no. If you need to receive a specific number of packets, use TCP. If you can afford to lose packets and you can rewrite your code not to expect a fixed number of them,  by all means use UDP.

Comment: In this example above I was only testing whether packets were getting lost and what transfer speeds I could achieve. I am considering an application where I can afford to lose some packets without any consequence, but at the same time would like faster transfer speed, and from what I can understand, since the UDP implementation is much simpler, it is therefore much faster if you're willing to accept limitations such as packet loss.

The other question is whether Java can be used to read raw frames on the Ethernet interface (bypass TCP/IP stack).I am reading up on a library called Jpcap now

Comment: If you are asking whether Jpcap could give you packet loss when reading raw packets, the answer is Yes.

Comment: No doubt, they will still be UDP packets so there will be losses. What about speed gains by bypassing the entire network stack and having access to raw packets?